# Is NATs Jetstream suitable for persiting messages forever?

Tags: nats.io

Can Jestream persist messages forever? So it will be the only source of truth like Kafka is often used? It means we can revind to the beginning anytime and consume all messages that went through some stream for example? Is Jestream suitable for this?

Answer (score 0):

As the [JetStream documentation](https://docs.nats.io/nats-concepts/jetstream#streaming-temporal-decoupling-between-the-publishers-and-subscribers) states, "queues are meant for workload distribution and consumption, not to be used as a mechanism for message replay". Of course, you could, I think...

Maybe the associated [key/yalue store](https://docs.nats.io/nats-concepts/jetstream/key-value-store) is what you are looking for. Values are immediately consistent and could provide a single source of truth.